# All Tabs instance view not updating

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on a tabs view for where i'm making three tabs of one component. I want to update tab component instance on active but its working only for first tab. When i select second or third tab its not updating views. I'm using same component for all tab.

I tried some solutions like `changeDetectRef` but all solutions only working for first tab.

```
<mat-tab-group class="tabs" (selectedTabChange)="onTabChanged($event)">
  <mat-tab label="Thousand"><m-number-bet[numberType]="'thousand'"></m-number-bet></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Hundred"><m-number-bet [numberType]="'hundred'"></m-number-bet></mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="Tens"><m-number-bet [numberType]="'ten'"></m-number-bet></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

onTabChanged(event: MatTabChangeEvent) {
  if (event.index === 0 || event.index === 1 || event.index === 2) {
      this.numberBetComponent.resetView();
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you already tried to do something like this: https://stackblitz.com/angular/rxkxvvegplv?file=app%2Ftab-group-dynamic-height-example.html

Comment: Yes i already see this example but this not exactly what i'm looking for i need to use same component for all tab. when i use same component for all tabs each tab have a instance of this component i need to update each instance of component.